# "ld: library not found for -lPods" only when run in real device

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I entered the mysterious phenomenon that I **can** build my app for simulator but I **can't** build for real device. The error is as below (which doesn't appear when build for simulator):

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-TechMoviePlus
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

(I'm using Cocoapods and attach one of my app's targets, so that the name of library is a little different.)

Project > Target > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries is as below:

[image]

Thank you for your kindness!

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning the **target** in **Podfile** has resolved the problem.

```
target :TechMoviePlus do
  pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
  pod "LBGIFImage"
end
```

Comment: Did not work for me... Did you do anything else besides changing the target?

Answer (score 0):

Open your pbxproj file with an editor and check for references to Pods-Application. If you renamed your application after pod install, you may have some references to the old pods.
Remove all the references to Pods-Application, launch xcode, full clean, and build.
It worked for me.